# Firestore skip batch update if value==null

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, papaparse

I use Papaparse to update data in  my Firestore database. If I don't want to update field i leave empty cell in CSV file. How to skip batch update/set if value == null.

```
var productHeight = value['productHeight'];
 batch.set(docRef, {
 productWeight: parseInt(productWeight),//if productWeight==null do nothing/skip update
...
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what's the issue... You simply need an if else statement in JS that checks for the value you are getting from your parser. Or even better if value!=null then do the normal flow you have. Here's a link that might help you properly write your if else statements: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

Comment: Hi Thx. I can't put if inside batch.set. It would be perfect to make if(productWeight!=null){productWeight: parseInt(productWeight)) - but it doesn't work. Maybe the question should be : how  skip update object element if value doesn't exists or How to keep value of key element if there are no changes? I understand I can use Firestore transaction to get this value and set again.

Comment: You can use the [`.set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.SetOptions.html#optional-merge) with merge to update fields in the document or create it if it doesn't exist. If this is not technically what you need, you can optionally add the if condition prior to using `batch.set()` to implement the logic. I think a Firestore transaction to do the checking would be good idea for this use case.